# How to move image on mouse move?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Please check the codepen link below

https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/mxOXQQ

I just want to ask that Can I replace my own image in place of the plus sign. Please help. I need to move my own image to move on mouse moment. If anyone knows how to do it please let me know. I need thsi to be integrated on my client's website

```
<canvas id="c" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>

canvas{
display: block;
box-sizing: border-box;  
border: solid 1px white;
width: 100%; */
}



var canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
var canvas2Context = canvas2.getContext("2d")
canvas2.width = canvas2.height = 20;
canvas2Context.lineWidth = 2;
canvas2Context.beginPath();
canvas2Context.moveTo(10, 0);
canvas2Context.lineTo(10, 20);
canvas2Context.moveTo(0, 10);
canvas2Context.lineTo(20, 10);
canvas2Context.stroke();

var Plus = function(){
this.x = 0;
this.y = 0;

this.left = 0;
this.top = 0;

this.width = 0;
this.height = 0;

this.scale = 1;
this.scale = 0.5;
}

Plus.prototype.draw = function(context){
context.setTransform(this.scale, 0, 0, this.scale,
this.left + this.x, this.top + this.y);

context.drawImage(
canvas2,
-10,
-10,
20,
20
)  

context.moveTo(0, -this.height/2);
context.lineTo(0, this.height/2);

context.moveTo(-this.width/2, 0);
context.lineTo(this.width/2, 0);
}

var c = document.getElementById('c');
var context = c.getContext('2d');

var signs = [];
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
var gridLength = 9;

var mouseMoved = false;
var mouseOver = false;

for(var i = 0; i < gridLength; i++){
signs[i] = [];

for(var j = 0; j < gridLength; j++){
var sign = new Plus();

sign.left = c.width/(gridLength + 1)  * (i + 1);
sign.top = c.height/(gridLength + 1) * (j + 1);

sign.width = 10;
sign.height = 10;

signs[i][j] = sign;
}
}

TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener('tick', draw);

function draw(){  
if(mouseOver && mouseMoved){
calculateIconPosition();
mouseMoved = false;
}


context.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
context.save();
context.beginPath();
for(var i = 0; i < gridLength; i++){
for(var j = 0; j <gridLength; j++){
var sign = signs[i][j];

sign.draw(context);
}
}  
context.closePath();
context.restore();
context.stroke();
}

function calculateIconPosition(){
for(var i = 0; i < gridLength; i++){
for(var j = 0; j < gridLength; j++){
var sign = signs[i][j];
var radius = 20;
var dx = mouse.x - sign.left;
var dy = mouse.y - sign.top;
var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) || 1;

var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

if(dist < radius){
radius = dist;
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.3, {scale: 2});
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.3, {scale: 1});
} else{
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.3, {scale: 1});
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.3, {scale: 0.5});
}

TweenMax.to(sign, 0.3,{
x: Math.cos(angle) * radius,
y: Math.sin(angle) * radius
})
}
}
}
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

function mouseMove(e){
var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top;  

mouseMoved = true;
}

c.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
mouseOver = true;
});

c.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
mouseOver = false;
for(var i = 0; i < gridLength; i++){
for(var j = 0; j < gridLength; j++){
var sign = signs[i][j];
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.3, {x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1});
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.3, {x: 0, y: 0, scale: 0.5});
}
}
})
```

Comment: @ Bhautik I tried exactly like codepen. I can't find that how to change the image

Comment: Because there is no image.

Comment: @is there any thing that i can put image in it like this link https://adsterra.com/ at top